# Are Opinion-Based Votes something we want?

Tags: discussion

I spend a fair amount of time lurking around here, and I have some opinions which aren't quite the norm, I will even admit they are a bit asocial, but does that grant the right for my opinion to be downvoted into the ground ? It hasn't happened to me personally, but I have seen perfectly phrased and constructed answers which just because some people didn't agree, they downvoted. I'm talking in some cases DOZENS of negative downvotes, which further imply it's all based on opinion, because someone had to scroll all the way down to even find it to downvote it some more.

I have a problem with people using votes to dictate their opinion, it goes against the objective of having quality over quantity, it also removes different perspectives for future people (since you get notifications for every answer made, I'm assuming the OP will still see it), and it hides possibilities

[Specific examples](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/172917/140150), which I find to answer the question effectively. This is not about any of these questions, nor do I want these to be mentioned, they are just to provide context.

Opinion-Based Votes are votes cast when you disagree with X, thus downvote answers that suggest OP to X, or you disagree with any/some implications of the OP's question and downvote to try and have that question not answered (refer to above questions)

Should we discourage/encourage opinion votes ? Or should quality reign supreme ?

EDIT:
I'd like to add that I'm not advocating for change, I'm just trying to understand the communities' stance on this, if I'm not happy ill simply leave and won't cause a fuss.

Comment: I think this question is sort of moot since you shouldn't really be answering with opinions anyway - there is even a vote to close option if a question is likely to solicit opinions "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."

Comment: @JackGifford In a perfect world, no one would, but we all have, and we all will Jack, yourself included.

Comment: Guilty as charged, I just wanted to be pedantic :-)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to just upvote any answer of mine if there is one.

Answer (score 9):

Votes are not policed in any way. People can vote up because they've had a good day or vote down because they stubbed their toe or don't like the grammar.

This is integral to how the site works. The only time votes are policed is when they're targeting a user which is mostly an automated process.

Answer (score 7):

Every vote on the network is opinion-based. [The Help Center explains up and down votes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) in a way that makes this obvious.

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Posts should be objective, but pretty much every judgment of quality in the form "good/no problems/has a problem" is subjective. Sometimes you can train a group so that their quality ratings are correlated (everyone agrees on what things constitute a problem that merits a downvote). People also tend to correlate better when judging quality relative to something else. If you ask people if something is *interesting* or *poorly researched* though, you are asking for an opinion.

If there were a completely objective measure of answer quality, there would be no need for people to vote.

Comment: "Well-researched, and useful" seems like a good way to objectively rate a good answer, if it isn't both of those, it should be downvoted. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: What makes you believe your *opinion* of what constitutes "well-researched" or "useful" is the standard everyone is using? Those are subjective measures. An objective measure is "conforms to modern English grammar as described in CGEL".

Comment: Research "a detailed study of a subject, especially in order to discover (new) information or reach a (new) understanding: "Researched by being just the past tense, means that something researched like an answer should lead to new information or understanding, if an answer doesn't lead to NEW contextual information or understanding (new perspective if I understood the meaning).Its not well researched.

Are you really telling me useful isn't an objective measure ? 

"Effective; helping you to do or achieve something" Means every answer should help you achieve something, effectively.

Comment: You can define all the words you want; the final judgement of whether to up or down vote in this system is subjective. Everyone has their own threshold for whether a particular quality of a post merits a vote one way or the other.

Comment: I didn't define anything, I used your given criteria that was "conforms to modern English grammar as described in CGEL", which was where I copied the meaning from. I'm not defining anything, I'm merely showing you, by your definition, that both those worlds are Objective Measures, which you said it was only my Opinion, like dictionaries were never a thing. What I think you're trying to get too, is if the question is Good or Bad, those are indeed constructs that can't be defined.

Comment: I didn't define any criteria. I gave an example of an objective measure hoping the contrast would help you distinguish between subjective and objective measures. Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: No problem, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know they are "opinion votes"? What makes something an opinion vote?

Let's take the example: all downvoted answers either say "stand your ground and quit your job!", which is literally "not helpful" to the question of how to handle this professionally and smoothly. It is also something trivial that nobody needs help on, "oh, just quit" is a non-answer.

Or the one that is left over that says "just don't go and wait till your boss is upset with you and calls you to their office" is almost worse. In my juristiction, you can have a valid argument about going or not going beforehand, but just ignoring your boss is going to get you fired. You are also in a much worse position to discuss this if you wait until your boss is angry with you.

So while I have not actually voted on any of them, I can see that they being "not useful" is not an opinion like "I like strawberry flavor". It is based on experience. The experience that this behavior as suggested in the answer will make it worse (assuming your goal is to keep your job and keep your boss reasonably happy => "smooth").

So if you are from an area where your experiences are different, lets say you can be fired for questioning the course, but you cannot be fired for just telling your boss to f--- off, then that is an interesting experience. But you will probably need to preface this with an explanation and make sure you recommend that for your specific area only. Because the majority of people, who can discuss training with their boss, but cannot just ignore them or talk to them constructively after having been cited into their office for an infraction,  will vote after their expert judgement. And if you imply that this behavior that works for you will work for them, too, they will say "no, not helpful, this would backfire immediately".

For example, Germany and the US have *wildly* different labor laws. If I didn't preface my posts with "In Germany...", I would get downvoted by all the US based people, that would read my post and think "this would never work". And they are right, it probably wouldn't work in the US and my post is better prefaced by the exact circumstances you need to make it work. On the other hand, I will ask for clarification or downvote people who answer questions about Germany or Europe with a mindset and solution clearly not adequate for those surroundings.

So to summarize: we don't encourage opinion. But we do encourage expert experience. And if you stray very far from the norm or don't make it visible that your advice is only for a specific subset of locations or people, the expert experience of many people might be "that would not work". And that is fine, because they are correct.

Comment: I have edited since clearly my intent was not visible at first. I'm sorry. 

If you have to start your answers with "In germany" either the questions are improperly tagged, or your experience is not adding anything to the current question since it's not in germany. It would be better to just edit it and place the tag "Germany" IMO, but you do you.

Comment: "And if you stray very far from the norm or don't make it visible that your advice is only for a specific subset of locations or people, the expert experience of many people might be "that would not work". And that is fine, because they are correct." - I'd love to see where all those experts are, because I haven't recognized a single one of them in this website from any books I've read on the matter. Most users are not expert at all in workplace issues, why do you think everyone is right ? Why do you think that just because you/me/they/them think something is wrong, means it is wrong ?

Comment: They don't "think" it is wrong. It **is** wrong. The Workplace is not a compiler, programming language or laws of physics that works the same world wide. My workplace in my country functions *very* differently from yours in your country. And yet you can be an expert in yours, as I would call myself an expert in mine. And we can advise exact opposite things and both be right in our respective countries or societies, but both would be horribly wrong in the others. So if you are unsure if advice is sound in all possible scenarios, you can either make it clear it is only for yours...

Comment: or live with the fact that other experts in their respective environments will let you know that your advice would never work for them.

Comment: I guess I'm just too cynical to believe strangers on the internet are experts, I mean they don't even need to prove it, as you just said, you call yourself an expert, yet I can't confirm if you are or not, thanks to anonymity (I mean this in a good way, about anonymity).

Shouldn't there be a screening to be classified as expert ? Like present a diploma in the field etc ? I can say I'm an expert at rocket propulsion, doesn't mean tesla is going to listen to me. (stupid example but you get the gist i hope)

Comment: And shouldn't the OP be the one to vote whether it would work for him, since he is the only person in his situation ? I know the world isn't a perfect place, I'm not expecting everyone to follow along, but have votes always been supposed to be just opinionated and not objective (in this SE) ?

Comment: "I guess I'm just too cynical to believe strangers on the internet are experts" Well, that is how SE works. If you doubt that, you may be better served by a different format, where people have been vetted to your liking. Maybe read books from authors you know and trust, or visit conferences or a university course.

Comment: "And shouldn't the OP be the one to vote whether it would work for him" they do. The OP is only person who can "accept" an answer. They can chose to accept the answer they prefer, even if it has downvotes.

Comment: Fair enough, wp

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t the voters are not experts either

Comment: Exactly my point on why it should be based on quality of answer/question, not on what the "experts" concur it would be best.

Comment: But who do you think should judge the quality of something, if not the experts?